# Unable to login with email or mobile

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to login with email or mobile (in PHP and MySQL). But I am unable to login.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE (email='$loginEmailOrMobile' AND password='$loginPassword') OR (mobile_number='$loginEmailOrMobile' AND password='$loginPassword')";
$mysql = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($mysql) == 1)
{
    echo "login successful";
    $user = mysql_fetch_object($mysql);
    echo $user->username;
}
else
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Did you know `mysql_` functions are deprecated and fully removed since `PHP 7.0`? You should consider switching over to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It's actually a well known fact that Jesus sacrificed himself so `mysql_` would be removed. Don't let his death be in vein.

Comment: Also look into the `prepare` method aswell so you can protect yourself better from SQL Injection (like you're currently vulnerable too. Btw)

Comment: i am getting a blank page

Comment: I can't see any syntax errors... try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script and return here with the output (amend it to your OP)

Comment: You'll get a blank page if you fill in the wrong username/password so your mobile might be adding an extra space to either the username or password.

Comment: There is soooooo much wrong here: deprecated `mysql_*` functions, sql injection, plain-text password storage, logged-in state not saved. You should start over.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript: in the same **vein** as your comment, I sometimes give warnings about SQL injection in **vain**, even if my volunteering to be a teacher makes me look **vain**. Sadly some code on Stack Overflow is a weather-**vane** for how hard it is to eradicate insecure practices.

Comment: @maththi-siva-charan , you have two input :- one is for email/mobile & other is  password & submit button is it right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have many problems in your code.

1. The mysql* extension is deprecated, and removed in PHP 7.
2. Plain passwords have poor security.
3. Prepared statements are recommanded when using variables.
4. You are handling an error when there is not.
5. You probably have no row (or more that 1) matching with your credentials so it's neither a success nor a MySQL error.

I will not cover all of this points in this answer in order to respect your original code, but I will try to explain many of them.
First, there is a tested and working code that does the job.

```php
<?php
//Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "databaseName");
//These variables may be set from $_POST or anywhere
//it is only an example
$loginEmailOrMobile = 'an-email@example.com';
$loginPassword = '123456';
//!!Vulnerable to SQL injections**
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE password = '$loginPassword' AND (email='$loginEmailOrMobile' OR mobile_number = '$loginEmailOrMobile')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

//Only if we got 1 result
if (1 === mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    $user = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    echo $user->email;
} else {
    die('We have not got only one result');
}
```

In this code you can see that:

- [Mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is used to perform the queries. It's really recommended to use mysqli instead of mysql for security reasons. Also, I'm using PHP 7 and I have not the mysql extension.
- Because the case you were handling with `mysql_error()` was not en error, I have removed it in order to handling the case. If I get 0, or even 2 results, that's not a MySQL error, but perhaps I have no user or more than 1 with that credentials.
- I have updated your SQL query in order to be less redundant but the logic is the same.

Your SQL query is not a prepared statement, I haven't touch it in order to respect your code and not to rewrite it entirely. But I really advise you to have a look at [mysqli prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

It seems you are currently using a plain password (unless you have already hashed it). It is recommanded to hash your passwords before inserting them into the database, and compare only the hashes. Please have a look to [crypt()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).